# Insert many documents into empty collection, update if document with same key already exist for mongodb

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have this list of dictionaries `json_data`

```
json_data = [
  {
    "CODE": "018906",
    "X": "29813.66349",
    "Y": "28697.520760000003"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "018907",
    "X": "30041.8389",
    "Y": "28602.98724"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "018910",
    "X": "31966.120789999997",
    "Y": "29115.75337"
  },
]
```

I have this mongodb collection `code_col`.
I want to insert `json_data` into collection `code_col` when the collecion is empty. There may be a new `json_data` next time and if the key `CODE` is the same, the document should be updated instead of inserted.

I am using python 3.7, pymongo, mongodb 4.2.7.

Comment: loop through the json_data and use `replace_one` using `CODE` as the filter and `upsert=True`. If still stuck post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Mongodb collection and a Python Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221575/merge-mongodb-collection-and-a-python-dict) --> Making it as dup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the `upsert` flag as `True`.

```py
for j in json_data:
    db.code_col.update_one({'CODE': j['CODE']},
                           {'$set': {'X': j['X'], 'Y': j['Y']}},
                           upsert=True)
```

Update: By using `bulk_write` method we can somewhat reduce the time for this operation.

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne

requests = []
for j in json_data:
    requests.append(UpdateOne({'CODE': j['CODE']},
                              {'$set': {'X': j['X'], 'Y': j['Y']}},
                              upsert=True))
db.code_col.bulk_write(requests)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your code and it seems quite slow when there are many documents to add. Is it possible to use update_many or replace_many to speed up the process?

Comment: I have herd about bulk operations in MongoDB, I haven't tried and I am not familiar with that. I will let you know once I try.

Comment: I have edited the answer, let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. One thing to edit. Last line should be `db.code_col.bulk_write(requests)`. The `s` is missing.